# Error when reading columns in txt file with python

Tags: python, readfile, indexoutofrangeexception, txt

I have a txt file with 1150 lines and 5 columns. The columns are separated with a tab.
I want to get arrays containing a certain column of the txt file. I use the following code to get the columns:

```
f = open(file, "r")
lines=f.readlines()
result=[]
for x in lines:
    result.append(x.split('\t')[0])
f.close()
```

With this I get all the values of my first column, but when I want to get the second column with

```
result.append(x.split('\t')[1])
```

I get an IndexError: list index out of range

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For debugging print `x` to see if it really have 5 fields

Comment: It does seem to have 5 fields. The output for the first 3 lines is: 0001 0 0001.PNG 0 0 

0002 0 0002.PNG 0 0 

0003 0 0003.PNG 0 0

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the lenght of each *x* within the loop:

```
print(len(line.split('\t')))
```

Comment: Thanks! I found the error, my txt file started with a line with just 1 column...